# Showing a div when hover on anchor with css?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hello I'm working on showing a shopping cart content `div.cart-dropdown` when I hover the mouse on the `a.cart-button`.

I can make the div show but when the mouse out the anchor `a.cart-button`, `div.cart-dropdown` disappear

Here is the code

```css
.cart-dropdown{
     display:none;
}

a.cart-button:hover + .cart-dropdown{
     display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="cart-button">Cart Button</a>

<div class="cart-dropdown">
  Cart dropdown content
</div>
```

How can I make the `div.cart-dropdown` visible when the mouse out `a.cart-button`

Must I use jQuery ?

Comment: Please try 
.cart-dropdown:hover {
     display: block;
}

Comment: with hover you will have to use javascript or something so that it remains in that state

Comment: Can't you put a `<div>` arround them and use the `:hover` on it? or maybe, put your `<div>` into the `<a>` tag... but this can be a bad practice

Comment: thank  @Patrick Ferreira

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple solution is putting both elements in a wrapper, and instead of showing the sibling, when `.cart-button` is hovered, show a child when the wrapper is.

```
<div class="dropdown-wrapper">
    <a href="#" class="cart-button">Cart</a>

    <div class="cart-dropdown">
       Cart dropdown content
     </div>
</div>

.dropdown-wrapper:hover .cart-dropdown {
    display: block;
 }
```

This way, even when the cursor moves to the dropdown menu, it's still within the `.dropdown-wrapper`, and will keep the menu in `display: block`

Comment: Yes, that's the answer. Thanks so much

Answer (score 4):

Try with this code, it may help you

```css
.cart-button {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.cart-dropdown {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    padding: 12px 16px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.cart-button:hover .cart-dropdown {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="cart-button">
  <a>Cart Button</a>
  <div class="cart-dropdown">
     Cart dropdown content
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add css class on mouseover event that add display block to the div of cart-dropdown:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".cart-button").one("mouseover", function() {
    $(".cart-dropdown").addClass('permahover');
});
</script>

<style>
.permahover{
    display: block;
}
</style>
```